# jQuery UI toggleClass

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I've asked a similar question to this before and I've looked at several similar Q&As already but non of them suit my requirements (or I simply don't have the js knowledge to get them to work!).

I have a [simple css/jquery menu](http://jsfiddle.net/jwoodcreative/abKhH/) set up which uses jQuery UI toggleClass to show and hide sub-menus.

I'd like to improve on this by closing any open sub-menu when another is clicked. Can anyone explain to me how to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your function:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('ul:not(.navhidden)').addClass('navhidden', 'fast');
```

Here's your fiddle, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/abKhH/1/

---

**P.S.** @Colin's solution also works, but I thing the above solution is a little nicer, since it opens and closes the panels simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I added a line to your jQuery that will make sure all the submenus are closed before opening the one that was clicked.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xXF5p/1/)

Comment: thanks, this works but @Joseph Silber's solution is a little smoother

Comment: I agree, his solution is nicer. I'm going to "borrow" it! :)

Answer (score 0):

A little slow on the response but it never hurts to have extra answers!
Edit: This does have a slight performance gain as it's only running the $('#main-nav a.dd') selector once due to chaining. If you're not familiar, .end() cancels out the .next() by going to the previous selection.

```
$('#main-nav a.dd').next().addClass('navhidden')
    .end().click(function() {
        $('#main-nav a.dd').not(this).next().each( function() {
            if ( !$(this).hasClass("navhidden") ) {
                $(this).addClass("navhidden");
            }
        });
        $(this).next().toggleClass('navhidden', 'fast');
        return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Qer7/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main-nav').hasClass('firstClass') ? $('#main-nav').addClass('SecondClass'): $('#main-nav').hasClass('firstClass');
```